# How to `docker import` ubuntu cloud image?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, tar

Trying to import an ubuntu cloud image from their website like this:

```
docker import http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz trusty-server-clouding
```

and getting this error:

```
Unhandled tar header type 83
```

Creating `Dockerfile` with `ADD trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz` doesn't do the trick neither, it just adds the tarball file into a container as is.

Comment: what are you doing here, an question and answer to be posted at same time?

Comment: Yeap. Was looking for right this question answered but only found the issue on the docker's github without a clear solution. And `tar` is not that easy to deal with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
curl http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-root.tar.gz | docker run -i --rm -w /tmp/image ubuntu bash -c 'tar -xzf - && tar -czf - .' | docker import --change 'CMD ["/bin/bash"]' - trusty-server-cloudimg
```

Check:

```
docker run -it --rm trusty- cat /etc/issueserver-cloudimg
#>>> Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l
```

### Explanation

This is a [feature-bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4066) in [Docker/Go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/634a848b8e3bdd8aed834559f3b2e0dfc7f5ae3a/pkg/archive/archive.go#L4) tar implementation, it can't handle some corner case tarballs created with a native `tar` utility with unusual options.

The simples way to fix this is just repack the tarball without any extra command line options like this:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/image
chdir /tmp/image
tar -xzf /some/broky.tar.gz
sudo tar -czf . /some/fixed.tar.gz
```

and then feed docker with it:

```
docker import /some/fixed.tar.gz fixed-image
```

For use in scripting, or on a different platform or if `sudo` is not present it is handy to just use docker to repack tarballs for itself:

```
docker run -i --rm -w /tmp/image ubuntu bash -c 'tar -xzf - && tar -czf - .'
```

You can pipe the broken tarball to this command and pipe its output to `docker import - image-name` as shown in the short answer above.